# Tests fail with CPU timeout - but only in Patch orgs

Tags: timeout, cpulimit, patch

This seems to be something new. Maybe a change in Salesforce.com server infrastructure. I am unable to upload patches of my product as some of its tests (run forever and then) fail with CPU Timeout limits.

- Have you seen this in your environment as well?
- Why does it happen?
- Is there anything we or Salesforce.com can do against it?

Comment: we are seeing it for last 4 months. In various instances mostly na* throw these  errors.

Comment: Do you have a case open for this you'd be willing to share the number of?

Comment: @ca_peterson:Sure it is...was Case 12982795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to Salesforce support this somewhat relates to this Known Issue [Enabling debug logs/opening developer console, can strongly affect the Apex CPU time when VF page utilizes a lot of getters and setters](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y6EAAU) and as workaround they recommend to:

1. Do not have Debug Logs against the running user
2. Do not have the developer console open
3. Debug the affected VF & Class in an Organization with lower quantity of Apex classes

Reading [this thread in the Partner Community](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?fId=0D53000002Hqm6nCAB&g=0F9300000001s8iCAA) also sheds some lights into the topic and should hinder you from expecting to much from Salesforce support regarding such issues ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is little effort to share what I know about these issues:

Have you seen this in your environment as well?

> Yes, In various Salesforce environment I have seen this issue. This
>   issue is not limited to Developer or Production instances. We have
>   seen this in full sandbox instances. Instances in which it has been
>   identified are na26, na2, na23 and cs10. There chances that it occur
>   in other instances but all are North American Instances. In addition
>   to CPU limit, SOQL Time out error has been seen on code which was
>   running fine for few years. Same issue has been posted in Salesforce
>   partner community.

Why does it happen?

> This issue started occurring right before release of Lightning
>   Experience and Winter '16. There is no official note about this error
>   but it is being fixed in several instances. This issue occurs in
>   random time frame. So you may get your test classes passed in some
>   time slot during a day.

Is there anything we or Salesforce.com can do against it?

> Case can be logged. But their is no official note about it. This will
>   be fixed eventually. We had it in few sandboxes, now they are working
>   fine without any code modification.

Comment: What did Salesforce.com tell you as root cause in you Support case? And how did they fix it. Did they move the Patch org to another instance?

Comment: I would grant you the bounty if you could give me details on how Salesforce solved this for you. If you could give me you case number I could basically reference it and ask for the same.

Comment: @RobertSösemann I would give you the case number If I have. Support team operate on overseas and it is hard to ask such information. However, if you have access to partner community, please go through https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001s8iCAA&fId=0D53000002Hqm6nCAB . It also has a case number if it could help you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes indeed.  It did happen but few were fixed automatically.  For other classes though, we split into batches.  Calling batch classes wherever possible. It worked for us.